# C++ multiple virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following hierarchy:

```
class A {
  virtual A* foo() = 0;
};

class B : A {
  virtual B* foo() = 0;
}

class C : B {
  C *foo();
}
```

Does class `B` need to inherit `A` as virtual?
What is the name for such pattern?

Comment: I'm not sure you are using the terms *virtual inheritance* and *multiple inheritance* with their official meaning.  What exactly is your question / problem, by the way?

Comment: @5gon12eder Probably, I dont know the proper term for this pattern.  Correct me if you know proper term.

Comment: Multiple inheritance means if a class inherits from two or more base classes in a single declaration as in `struct C : A, B`. Virtual inheritance means that a derived class does not obtain a base sub-object but rather a pointer to a base-object.  It is written as `struct B : virtual A`.  Virtual inheritance is used most frequently together with multiple inheritance to ensure there is exactly one base object.  Does your question refer to these concepts?

Comment: If all you wanted to ask is whether you should write `C *foo();` or `virtual C *foo();` in `C`, then the answer is that it doesn't matter.  The `virtual` will be implicit here.  But I'm not sure that this was your question.

Comment: @5gon12eder my question is if it should be `class B : virtual A` and what is the name for a pattern of inherting a hierarchy of virtual functions.

Comment: I don't think there's a special name for inheriting a virtual function in a chain. There's a name for changing the return type based on the derived class type, but I'm having trouble remembering what it's called. It's a special case, most of the time a derived class function must have the same return type as the parent class function.

Comment: Whether it should or should not depends on what you're actually trying to accomplish.  Both versions are valid C++.  Could you please explain in your question what problem you are trying to solve?  You are also not “inheriting a hierarchy of virtual functions”.  There is exactly one function, `foo`, and it's overridden in each of your derived classes.

Comment: @MarkRansom Is what I am trying to do ok or is there a pitfall somewhere?

Comment: @MarkRansom It's called [*covariance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: You really do have to be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish. And thanks @5gon12eder.